# pandas.read_sql is extremely slow on python 3 kernel compared to python 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas, pandasql

I have a simple parameterized select query hitting an Oracle database via pyodbc connection and fetching data in a dataframe via pandas.read_sql. 
The code is super efficient and fast in Python 2 kernel whereas, extremely slow in Python 3.

Following is the code:

```
import pandas
import pyodbc
import time

connection = pyodbc.connect('dsn=oracle;userid=userid;pwd=password')
sql = """
select * from order_table
where 
order_key = ?
"""
start_time = time.time()
dataframe = pandas.read_sql(sql=sql, con=connection, params=['key-1'])

print(time.time()-start_time)
```

Python 2 execution time:
0.193000078201

Python 3 execution time:
53.687000036239624

Comment: Which versions of `pandas` and `pypyodbc` are you using?

Comment: Is the environment (except the Python version) *exactly* the same... eg - you're accessing the same database with the same schema, searching for the same key with the DB at about the same workload, checked there hasn't been any transaction locks preventing your read occurring immediately etc... etc...?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Everything remains the same. In the Jupyter Notebook, I go to "Kernel" => "Change Kernel" => "Python 3/2".

Comment: pyodbc version 4.0.24, pandas version 0.23.4